# Firefox not rendering menu image correctly

Tags: css, firefox, menu

Hi all – I was wondering if anyone could offer any insight into a problem I am having, which I can't get my head around. Initially it was a problem with Chrome, but since having fixed that it is now with Firefox.

Check out the following left menu image. When it renders Firefox, the "go" button hovers underneath for some reason. This does not occur in other browsers.

Firefox menu: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/254/20212630.jpg/

For other browsers: http://cit.edu.au/future

Comment: Works on ff13.0.1 what version are you using?

Comment: could you please show your code so that we can help

Comment: Here is the HTML and CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/yXaJE/

Answer (score 0):

Now define your css

```
#quickAccess .askUs form, #site-search {
position:relative;
}

#quickAccess .accessBox input.formSearch{
right:0;
}
```

Comment: Is it the border right which you need me to change to 0 pixels?